# Theoretical q-q plot: What does the f-value mean in this example?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, normalization, qq-plot

I am looking at [this article](https://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Week06a.html) on theoretical q-q plots and am trying to understand it in its entirety. The part where I get lost is when the author writes:

> We first find the f-values for alto

What do the f-values represent here? I see that these are f-values for each alto singer's height value, but I don't really understand what that means. What does the f-value of a given height value actually represent?

The author then goes on to find the matching normal distribution values from those f-values. To do this, they use the qnorm (quantile) function in R. What exactly is going on here? It looks like this function is performing some standardisation to convert the f-values to values that follow a normal distribution, centred on zero with a standard deviation of 1. Is this correct and if so can someone explain how this is achieved?

Thanks

Comment: It's the empirical cumulative distribution function.

Comment: They are ranks rescaled to fit into the interval $(0,1)$: if you had ten, then the values would be $0.05$, $0.15$, $0.25$, $0.35$, $0.45$, $0.55$, $0.65$, $0.75$, $0.85$, $0.95$  and then applying `qnorm` would turn these into something like a standard normal distribution $-1.645, -1.036, -0.674, -0.385, -0.126\ldots$ and the positive equivalent,

Comment: "$f$-value" is a nonstandard term (and quite nondescriptive, making it difficult even to guess).